# Help with "Expression as an assignment target" error

Tags: sql, plsql

simple question here, I am writing a function, but I was having trouble setting up my first if statement, my attempt is below, but I keep getting "Expression can not be used as an assignment target" error on the lines "Type := CE;" and "Type :=UG;" Im sure there is a quick fix to this...... anyone know?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SCHEMA1."FUNCTION1" (   Id   IN VARCHAR2,
                                                   term IN VARCHAR2,
                                                   Type IN VARCHAR2 default NULL )
RETURN VARCHAR2 IS


BEGIN
IF Type IS NULL
THEN
    IF SUBSTR(term,5,6) = 'Q'
    THEN
        Type := 'CE';
    ELSE
        Type := 'UG';
    END IF;
END IF;
........
```

Comment: "Type" here is an input param.  If you mean to change it, make it an in out parameter.

Comment: Okay, easy solution, makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare a holding variable for use within the function?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SCHEMA1."FUNCTION1" (   Id   IN VARCHAR2,
                                                   term IN VARCHAR2,
                                                   Type IN VARCHAR2 default NULL )
RETURN
  VARCHAR2
IS
  iType VARCHAR2;    
BEGIN

iType := Type;

IF iType IS NULL
THEN
    IF SUBSTR(term,5,6) = 'Q'
    THEN
        iType := 'CE';
    ELSE
        iType := 'UG';
    END IF;
END IF;
........
```

Comment: Okay, this runs fine, Thanks! Follow up question though......I am just curious, why does this work, because from what I am seeing it is doing virtually the same thing.  Is it just the difference between assigning something to a parameter vs. assigning something to a variable?

Comment: I'm not an Oracle expert, so this is how I've rationalised it to myself in the past : The parameters of an Oracle Function behave as if they're references to the 'objects' being passed in.  By assigning a new value to the parameter, you're assigning a new value to whatever was used as the input.  But the input could have been the concatenation of two fields, and so it's impossible to determine what should be updated.  That's a really wooly explanation I know, maybe someone better informed will answer this for you :)

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me like you're passing 'Type' in as an argument and then trying to assign to it. Is your intent to RETURN 'CE'/'UG' based on Term? If so, introduce a new variable or change Type := to RETURN.